# How to run a javascript code in elementor after page loading is completed?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, load, elementor

So I am using the "tabs" widget in elementor pro. I need the page to start in a particular tab on load. I figured I can do that using:

`document.getElementById('tab-id').click();`

but I need this js code to run after the page has loaded completely. I tried to use "defer" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I searched around a bit and found this solution:

```
<script defer="defer"  
type="text/javascript" >
inite=0;
 setInterval(function(){
     if (document.readyState == "complete" && inite == 0 )  {
      document.getElementById('elementor-tab-title-2082').click();
      inite++;
    }
 }, 500);
</script>
```

I added this by simply adding the code to a "HTML" widget at the end of the page.

So what this does is every half second a script runs to check if the page is fully loaded by using document.readyState.

once the page is ready inite gets nonzero and tab gets clicked.

working perfectly..